# Webpack css-loader: Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error

Tags: webpack

I have a project where I need to move from *browserify* to *webpack*, I get an error when importing a CSS file from an external node_module:

```
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: 
  Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css in ...
```

The line provoking this error is located in a CSS file: (inside this external node library I cannot modify)

```
@import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

It works when I comment it and add the same CSS using a *require* in a JS file:

```
require("font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

This is not a solution, since I cannot change the file. So I tried to do an *resolveLoader.alias* in the *webpack.config.js*:

```
alias: {
    'font-awesome': path.join(process.cwd(), 'url to font-awesome/')
}
```

Or even trying to exclude this library... but no luck.

I am new to webpack so I am still confused and tried many different things based on documentation, but running out of ideas. How would you fix this?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but **resolveLoader** is definitely not what you've needed, because it uses for loader aliases. For module aliases use **resolve**.